# Restricting users in Docker group to not run privileged containers

Tags: security, docker

Docker daemon runs as root. Once we add a user to the Docker group, he can launch any docker container even privileged containers. This seems to be a serious security issue.

Is there a way of limiting some users in the Docker group to not be able to run privileged containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to restrict access to privileged containers.  This is why, for example, Fedora has dropped the `docker` group (because granting access to docker is effectively just like granting passwordless `sudo` access).

If you want to provide "docker-as-a-service", you probably want to put something like in front of it like [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io), which provides only indirect access to the Docker API and can be configured to permit or deny the use of privileged containers.

Comment: It may be simpler to write a REST proxy for the Docker API than to install Kubernetes.

Comment: Sure, if writing a REST proxy is easier than using some off-the-shelf software (and it may be, it depends on the deployer).  I wonder if there is maybe already a filtering REST proxy available out there...

Answer (score -1):

Many Docker users are enforcing and restricting SElinux by changing the domain of Docker users "SecurityContext"